# Alter Javascript on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, resize, window

first post here; apologies for any information that is missed. I'm a complete novice at Javascript so apologies in advanced also.

I am currently creating a responsive website with a slider.

The slider takes up the entire background of the site on larger devices, but when the window is less than 480px I would like the slider to scale down to a smaller area.  I have this working correctly, in terms of when the device first loads up the page.  The correct slider settings are being used.

**But what I would like is: if the user scales the website below 480px then the javascript will change at that point (like CSS media queries) to use the new slider settings.  At the moment, if you scale below or above the threshold, you have to refresh the page to get the new slider settings.**

This is some code I managed to find from other questions asked on the site, but it does not allow the change to happen when the window is resized, only on a refresh:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

if($(window).width()>480){
$(".slideshow").startslider({
    slideTransitionSpeed: 500,
    slideTransitionEasing: "easeOutExpo",
    sliderFullscreen: true,
    sliderAutoPlay: false,
    sliderResizable: true,
    slidesDraggable: false,
    slideImageScaleMode: "fill",
    showTimer: false,
    showPause: false,
    showDots: false
    });
return;
} else {

$(".slideshow").startslider({
    slideTransitionSpeed: 500,
    slideTransitionEasing: "easeOutExpo",
    sliderFullscreen: false,
    sliderAutoPlay: false,
    sliderResizable: true,
    slidesDraggable: true,
    slideImageScaleMode: "fill",
    showTimer: false,
    showPause: false,
    showDots: false
    });
}
});
</script>
```

I am completely new to Javascript, so this may be a simple problem; but it's beyond me all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your code inside a function like this:

```
function slider() {
    // your code here
}
```

which is then called on page load:

```
$(function(){
    slider();
});
```

and also on window resize:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    slider();
});
```

Comment: Sorry Migg, tried to reply but realised there is a maximun character limit, by any chance do you have a JSfiddle of this? I can't seem to get it to work with my own code, really need to up my 'javascript' game! I think I'm putting my code in the wrong place?

Comment: "your code" starts with `if($(window).width()>480){` and you have to leave out `});</script>` at the end. Did that help?